# In asp.net MVC if the url has a parameter , does the route have to be registered?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my limited (2 weeks) experience in asp.net MVC3, for most action methods, I have never needed to add a route registration. But I have noticed that if the action method has an input parameter, then I can't access the method with a url of the form www.mysite.com/myController/myAction/myParameter1/myParameter2/myParameter3  (without the ? mark ) unless I map the route. Is that how its supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you already have registered route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

it accepts one parameter, named id, so your action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string id)
```

will "catch" the request:

```
www.mysite.com/MyController/MyAction/parameter_value
```

and `id` will get value "parameter_value".

If you need more than one parameter (or parameter has to be names something else than "id"), then you have to register new route.

In case when you have 2 parameters, you will register route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", 
                    "{controller}/{action}/{parameter1}/{parameter2}", 
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", parameter1 = UrlParameter.Optional, parameter2=UrlParameter.Optional } 
                );
```

and your action might be:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string parameter1, int? parameter2)
```

Comment: Modified the question to include more than one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to register the route customizing the route in `global.asax` according to your requirement.You have to register the route in following way:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "routeName",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{myParameter}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", myParameter= "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

So with above route, it ensures that whenever your url goes in above format, the parameter right after `"action/"` will be taken as parameter.....

For more than one parameter in your url, you can register like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "routeName",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{myParameter1}/{myParameter2}/{myParameter3}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", myParameter1= "", myParameter2= "", myParameter3= "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```